# Strong-typed Linq to construct OData query options

Tags: c#, linq, odata

Assume the following example that demonstrates how to perform read operation using  [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = webUri;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var requestUrl = "/api/products?$filter=(Category eq 'Cars')";

    var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
       var products = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Product>>();
    }
}
```

So far so good, but what about constructing REST endpoint Url from a Linq query?

To summarize, the goal is to utilize strong-typed Linq expression for constructing REST endpoint Url, for example the query:

```
var products = client.Get<List<Product>>().Where(p => p.Category == "Cars");
```

will be transformed into:

```
/api/products?$filter=(Category eq 'Cars')
```

Are there any .Net library that allows to transform Linq expression into OData query option string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WCF Data Service client to build the query for you then parse out the result.

```
// url doesn't matter unless you will use data service to execute the call
var dsContext = new DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://stackoverflow"));
// need to pass in the controller into CreateQuery - could create an extension method to pluralize the type to not have to pass it in. 
var query = dsContext.CreateQuery<Product>("/api/products").Where(p => p.Category == "Cars");
// ToString will output the url
var uri = new Uri(query.ToString());
// Grab just the path and query
var path = new Uri(uri.PathAndQuery, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
await client.GetAsync(path); // this will call the api not DataServiceContext
```

But if you are going to use DataServiceContext then you might just want to use it to execute the query for you instead of using httpclient - this works for OData V1-3 I don't know if it works for V4.  The query variable will be an IQueryable and you could just execute it.