# How to generate OData filter string in dotnet core

Tags: .net-core, odata

I can find hundreds of examples of how to build an OData API, but i'm consuming an OData API.

At the moment we're doing something horrible like;

```cs
string filter = "FirstName eq '" + firstName + "' " +
"LastName eq '" + lastName + "'";
```

But i'm assuming there's a library I can use and do something like;

```cs
SomeType query = new SomeType();
query.AddFitler("FirstName", Comparison.Equals, firstName);
query.AddFilter("LastName", Comparison.Equals, lastName);
string filter = query.ToString();
```

Could you point me in the right direction please- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i've found the solution after half a day of searching [Strong-typed Linq to construct OData query options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837485/strong-typed-linq-to-construct-odata-query-options)

```cs
// url doesn't matter unless you will use data service to execute the call
var dsContext = new DataServiceContext(new Uri("http://stackoverflow"));
// need to pass in the controller into CreateQuery - could create an extension method to pluralize the type to not have to pass it in. 
var query = dsContext.CreateQuery<Product>("/api/products").Where(p => p.Category == "Cars");
// ToString will output the url
var uri = new Uri(query.ToString());
// Grab just the path and query
var path = new Uri(uri.PathAndQuery, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
await client.GetAsync(path); // this will call the api not DataServiceContext
```

Just testing now!

**EDIT** this worked well- I ended up creating a little wrapper to DRY it up a bit;

```cs
public class SearchQueryBuilderService<T>
{
    private DataServiceContext _context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri("https://tickett.net"));

    public string Build(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _context.CreateQuery<T>("tel").Where(predicate).ToString().Replace("https://tickett.net/tel?$filter=", "");
    }
}
```

So I can now call this from various "Api Repositories" like;

```cs
string searchString = new SearchQueryBuilderService<SomePoco>().Build(sp => sp.SomeProp == "SomeValue");
```